# Correctly Defining Relationship for Deletes in EF Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am getting the following error when I remove an entity from a collection and then persist it back.  I understand that I need to setup my relationships to delete the entity when the relationship is removed, but I am unable to figure out exactly what needs to be done despite searching via Google and SO.

> The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the
>   foreign-key properties is non-nullable.

I have three tables: Role, Permission, and RolePermission.  I am trying to remove a RolePermission from a Role.

```
public RoleMap()
{
    HasKey(t => t.Id);
    ToTable("Role");
    Property(t => t.RoleName).HasColumnName("RoleName");

    HasMany(t => t.RolePermissions).WithRequired(t => t.Role).HasForeignKey(t => t.RoleId);
}

public PermissionMap()
{
    HasKey(t => t.Id);
    ToTable("Permission");
    Property(t => t.ApplicationId).HasColumnName("ApplicationId");
    Property(t => t.PermissionName).HasColumnName("PermissionName");
    Property(t => t.IsActive).HasColumnName("IsActive");

    HasRequired(t => t.Application).WithMany(t => t.Permissions).HasForeignKey(t => t.ApplicationId);
}

public RolePermissionMap()
{
    HasKey(t => t.Id);
    ToTable("RolePermission");
    Property(t => t.PermissionId).HasColumnName("PermissionId");
    Property(t => t.RoleId).HasColumnName("RoleId");

    HasRequired(t => t.Permission).WithMany(t => t.RolePermissions).HasForeignKey(t => t.PermissionId);
    HasRequired(t => t.Role).WithMany(t => t.RolePermissions).HasForeignKey(t => t.RoleId);
}
```

The code to remove looks like this (everything is attached to the DBContext):

```
foreach (RolePermission rolePermission in permissionsToRemove)
{
   role.RolePermissions.Remove(rolePermission);
}

//call commit/saveChanges here
```

What do I need to setup in order for Remove to actually cause a delete?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need the RolePermission entity at all, unless you're storing more information in addition to the foreign key fields. So, try to building a many-to-many relationship between Role and Permission. Let me show you an example with my own code:

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(u => u.Roles)
            .WithMany(r => r.Users)
            .Map(x => {
                x.ToTable("USER_ROLE_XREF", dbsch);
                x.MapLeftKey("ID_USER");
                x.MapRightKey("ID_ROLE");
            });
```